# Need suport in order to create 2 buttons

Tags: javascript, html, plc

I have created a html interface for a PLC. In this interface I created two buttons that should activate two individual bits in the PLC. The problem is that the first one is working but the second one is not working, even if I comment or delete the first one and I don't understand why. I don't have experience with html, or javascript, I tried to read on the internet how it should be done, but now I am stuck.

IOserver.htm code

```
<!-- AWP_In_Variable Name='"WebInterface".startFilling' -->
<!-- AWP_In_Variable Name='"WebInterface".startDraining' -->

...

"fillingActivatedFdbk":":="WebInterface".fillingActivatedFdbk:",
"drainActivatedFdk":":="WebInterface".drainActivatedFdk:",
"startFilling":":="WebInterface".startFilling:",
"startDraining":":="WebInterface".startDraining:",
```

html code:

```
<!-- AWP_In_Variable Name='"WebInterface".startFilling' -->
<!-- AWP_In_Variable Name='"WebInterface".startDraining' -->

...

<button type="submit" id="startFilling" bgcolor="enButtonStatus" class="button">
<span>Start filling</span>
</button> <br>
<button type="submit" id="startDraining" bgcolor="startDrainingStatus" class="button">
<span>Start draining</span>
</button>`
```

Javascript code

```
var color = [/*white*/"#FFFFFF",/*green*/"#0BEA00",/*red*/"#FF0000",/*yellow*/"#FBFF00",/*grey*/"#CACACD"];
var startFillingStatus = document.getElementById('startFilling');
var startDrainingStatus = document.getElementById('startDraining');

...

(function () {
var $$ = function (selector) {
return Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(selector));
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {

...

//Start filling button function

document.getElementById("startFilling").onclick = function () { fillingButtonFunction() };
var fillingButton = document.getElementById('startFilling').value;
function fillingButtonFunction() 
{
fillingButton = !fillingButton;
url = "IOServer.htm";
name = '"WebInterface".startFilling';
sdata = escape(name) + '=' + fillingButton;
$.post(url, sdata, function (result1) { });
}

//Start draining button function

document.getElementById("startDraining").onclick = function () { drainingButtonFunction() };
var drainingButton = document.getElementById('startDraining').value;
function drainingButtonFunction() 
{
drainingButton = !drainingButton;
url = "IOServer.htm";
name = '"webInterface".startDraining';
sdata = escape(name) + '=' + drainingButton;
$.post(url, sdata, function (result2) { });
}

...

// Start filling button color

if (result["fillingActivatedFdbk"] == true) {
startFillingStatus.style.backgroundColor = color[3];
}
else {
startFillingStatus.style.backgroundColor = color[0];
}

// Start draining button color

if (result["drainActivatedFdk"] == true) {
startDrainingStatus.style.backgroundColor = color[3];
}
else {
startDrainingStatus.style.backgroundColor = color[0];
}
```

Start filling button is working, but start draining button is not working. I don't overwrite the bits in the PLC. The logic is done in the same way for both buttons. Any advice is wellcome.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: At `drainingButtonFunction()`, `name = '"webInterface".startDraining';` should be `name = '"WebInterface".startDraining';` with the capital W of WebInterface.

Comment: Unbelievable! I don't know how I miss that. Thanks a lot!!